# Laravel: Using validator's sometimes method when input is an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form that posts a `structure` field as an array. The `structure` array contains definitions of database table columns.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'structure' => 'required|array|min:1',
    'structure.*.name' => 'required|regex:/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9_]+$/',
    'structure.*.type' => 'required|in:integer,decimal,string,text,date,datetime',
    'structure.*.length' => 'nullable|numeric|required_if:structure.*.type,decimal',
    'structure.*.default' => '',
    'structure.*.index' => 'required_if:is_auto_increment,false|boolean',
    'structure.*.is_nullable' => 'required_if:is_auto_increment,false|boolean',
    'structure.*.is_primary' => 'required_if:is_auto_increment,false|boolean',
    'structure.*.is_auto_increment' => 'required_if:structure.type,integer|boolean',
    'structure.*.is_unique' => 'required_if:is_auto_increment,false|boolean',
    'structure.*.decimal' => 'nullable|numeric|required_if:structure.*.type,decimal|lt:structure.*.length',
]);
```

Without going into explanation of all the rules, one thing should be made sure that the `length` field is always `null` when the `type` is not `string` or `decimal` as you cannot assign a length to columns other than these types. So, I am trying to use the `sometimes` method on the `$validator` instance.

```
$validator->sometimes('structure.*.length', 'in:null', function ($input) {
    // how to access the structure type here?
});
```

My question is inside the closure, how do I make sure that the `length` is `null` only for the array element that has the `type` set to other than `string` or `decimal`.

I have tried the `dd` function and it seems the whole input array is passed to the closure.

```
$validator->sometimes('structure.*.length', 'in:null', function ($input) {
    dd($input);
});
```

Here is the output of the `dd` method.

[image: Output of the <code>dd</code> method]

I can use a `foreach` construct but wouldn't that be inefficient? Checking all the elements for a single element?

How do I check the type only for the array element under consideration?

Is there a Laravel way to do this?

Comment: What's the output of `dd($input)` inside the closure?

Comment: @Mozammil Question updated!

Answer (score 1):

How about thinking opposite? if the Type is String or Decimal, the Length field will become Required.

```
$validator->sometimes('structure.*.length', 'required', function ($input) {
    return $input->type == 'string' or $input->type == 'decimal';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question. I took a look at the API for [sometimes()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L859). It seems, what you want to do, is currently not possible with it.

A possible alternative *could* be to use an **After Validation Hook**. For example:

```php
$validator->after(function ($validator) {
    $attributes = $validator->getData()['structure'];

    foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
        if(! in_array($value['type'], ['string', 'decimal']) && ! is_null($value['length'])) {
            $validator->errors()->add("structure.{$key}.length", 'Should be null');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not sure if I should be marking this answer correct since I am asking for something that is not possible and people will keep posting alternate approaches. However, in the interest of keeping things lightweight, your answer seems to be the best one as there is no need to create classes. One comment though. `$attributes = array_values(array_only($validator->getData(), 'structure'));` can be simplified to `$attributes = $validator->getData()['structure'];`. If no, can you explain a bit why you choose to go that way?

Comment: You could do that. Just a matter of personal preference I guess. It won't fail if for some reason `structure` is not present in the array.

Comment: The validation rules I have posted in the question make sure that `structure` is an array and has atleast one element.